# How to wrap text in a div on a single row of divs (CSS2 - dompdf compatible)?

Tags: html, css, dompdf

Having a table row looking set of divs, how does one ensure the last div doesn't extend beyond the parent, instead breaking into lines and remaining at the end of the row (CSS2 only):

[image]

```css
.foo { width: 50%; white-space: nowrap;}

.foo > div {
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: normal;
}

.a, .b, .c { width: 150px; background: yellow;}
.d { width: auto; }
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='a'>a</div>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
  <div class='d'>this text is very long it should break into lines</div>
</div>
```

With this being the expected result (achieved using `display: contents`) which isn't compatible with my PDF generator dompdf:
[image]

```css
.foo { width: 100%; }

.foo > div {
  float: left;
}

.a, .b, .c { width: 150px; background: yellow; }
.d { width: auto; display: contents;  }
.e { white-space: normal; display: table-cell; }
```

```html
<div class='foo'>
  <div class='a'>a</div>
  <div class='b'>b</div>
  <div class='c'>c</div>
  <div class='d'>
    <div class='e'>this text is very long is should break into lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: according to your description, there's no reason why `.d` should be `display: inline-block`. Why don't you try `.d { display: block }`?

Comment: _"(CSS2 only)"_ - reason ...? Not sure if there is a way then, anything that comes to mind (flexbox, calc(), etc.), is beyond the scope of CSS2.

Comment: Are you open to JavaScript to support features from CSS3 not in CSS2? (feels like a PDF generator  is in play here...or something similar)

Comment: Using an _actual_ table, and applying `table-layout:fixed;`, might be about the only way to get what you want, with that "CSS2 only" requirement.

Comment: When you say "should break into lines" do you want it to do that on the SAME line i.e. stacked within the space for that last block or start on the NEXT line like for example a `<p>` would do? "table row looking" seems to say the former.  Kind of feels like an X-Y problem ATM.

Comment: Without knowing more it might be something like changing the `.d {
      display: table-cell;
      vertical-align: middle;
    }` display BUT the way you have stated your title says `display: inline-block;` only.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss yes - it's a PDF generator situation. I started with a `<table>` but ran into problems with widths. The `inline-block` is only there to stack the divs on the horizontal plane. The idea is to resemble a table so the text in the last div breaks into lines while remaining at the far right side of the view.

Comment: @CBroe CSS2 only because this view is rendered by a PDF generator which doesn't support CSS3 :/

Comment: Wouldn't you want to get rid of the `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: From a comment I added the DOMPDF tag

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your PDF Generator to test but perhaps as simple as this:

Based on comment I jumped to conclusion it may require the full context of the CSS so I added a wrapper with `display: table;` re:
`.container-wrapper { display: table; }` which behaves like a `table` and a
`.container-wrapper .foo { display: table-row-group;` which behaves like `tbody` so that perhaps it can pick up the `display: table-cell;` as a `td`.

I did a quick look and there are a lot of open issues at the moment in github on

> DOMPDF

```css
.container-wrapper {
  display: table;
}

.container-wrapper .foo {
  display: table-row-group;
}

.foo>* {
  display: table-cell;
  /* vertical-align: middle; only if you want true table look */
}

.a,
.b,
.c {
  width: 150px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-wrapper">
  <div class='foo'>
    <div class='a'>a</div>
    <div class='b'>b</div>
    <div class='c'>c</div>
    <div class='d'>this text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis
      text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis
      text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into linesthis text is very long it should break into lines</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, DOMPDF doesn't like 'table-cell'..

Comment: Maybe you need to full set - but I did note over 500 issues open on that DOMPDF (assuming I found the right thing here) https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf  I don't have time or motivation to dig into all those to see if any are related to this.

Comment: Appreciate your help. Make that 501! I was hoping there was an old-school HTML solution for this.